# Plot irregular circle in latex

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw figure of attached file in LaTex?

[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](//tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Answer (score 25):

Welcome. You can add random deformations on a smooth plot.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr=1.5*(1+0.1*rnd);}]
 \draw[clip] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] (\t:rr);
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {red,blue,green!70!black}
 {\draw[\X] plot[smooth,variable=\t,samples at={0,0.25,...,1.75}] 
 (15+8*rnd+120*\Y:\t);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Surely you may animate this, too.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\foreach \X in {1,...,42}
{\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path[use as bounding box] (-1.8,-1.8) rectangle (1.8,1.8);
 \draw[clip] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] (\t:{1.5*(1+0.1*rnd)});
 \foreach \X [count=\Y starting from 0] in {red,blue,green!70!black}
 {\draw[\X] plot[smooth,variable=\t,samples at={0,0.25,...,1.75}] 
 ({15+6*(rnd-0.5)+120*\Y}:\t);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 14):

Just for fun purposes. Let other experts implement the randomly distorted radii.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}%
\psLoop{25}{%
\begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{360}{Rand 5 div 1.5 add t PtoC}{P}
    \psnccurve(0,\numexpr\Pnodecount-1){P}
    \psline[linecolor=red](P0)
    \psline[linecolor=green](P3)
    \psline[linecolor=blue](P6)
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

## Edit

No PSTricks, no party!

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}%
\psLoop{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{360}{Rand 1 add t PtoC}{P}
    \psnccurve(0,\numexpr\Pnodecount-1){P}
    \foreach \i/\c in {0/red,3/green,6/blue}{%
       \pnode(P\i){T}
       \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{N-T.x N-T.y Pyth}{t Rand 0.5 sub 10 mul N-T.y N-T.x atan add PtoC}{Q}
       \psncurve[linecolor=\c](0,\Qnodecount){Q}}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually I can make the randomly distorted radii using `\curvepnodes` but this page is too narrow for the extra code.

Comment: with package `xfp`:  `\fpeval{rand()*5}` for real numbers between 0 and 5

Comment: @WellHarassedProgrammer: is that a reference to Fermat and his last theorem?

Comment: @Tommiie: You are well informed. :-)

Comment: @WellHarassedProgrammer: I very much like this theorem and when I find a book on it, I love reading it.

Comment: I know the reason why I got fewer up votes. Because they thought that my second code (that produces the amoeba-like closed curve) cannot produce the required result which is a distorted circle.