# What makes the green line unable to reach the corresponding vertex of the polygon?

Tags: pstricks, pst-node

What makes the green line unable to reach the corresponding vertex of the polygon?

[image]

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}%
\psLoop{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{360}{Rand 1 add t PtoC}{P}
    \psnpolygon(0,\numexpr\Pnodecount-1){P}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{N-P3.x N-P3.y Pyth}{t N-P3.y N-P3.x atan PtoC}{Q}
    \psnline[linecolor=green](0,\Qnodecount){Q}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

## Edit

The problem  gone if I buffer the node `P3` as follows.

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}

\begin{document}
\pstVerb{realtime srand}%
\psLoop{10}{%
\begin{pspicture}[saveNodeCoors](-2,-2)(2,2)
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=10]{0}{360}{Rand 1 add t PtoC}{P}
    \psnpolygon(0,\numexpr\Pnodecount-1){P}
    \pnode(P3){T}
    \curvepnodes[plotpoints=50]{0}{N-T.x N-T.y Pyth}{t N-T.y N-T.x atan PtoC}{Q}
    \psnline[linecolor=green](0,\Qnodecount){Q}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: My guess is that there are two different random number at work: one when you draw the vertex and one when you draw the green line. That is, Rand gets evaluated twice.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: It is counter intuitive. :-)

Comment: At least in Ti*k*Z this happens and is a standard pit fall. It is also the reason why `declare function={rr=1.5*(1+0.1*rnd);}` in [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/508415/194703) works.

Comment: the _saved_ nodes are global, so you overwrite the `P3` with the next run. With `\pnode(P3){T}` you save the global node `P3` into the local one `T`

Comment: @user187802: Thank you. It is a nice feature. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-node,pst-plot}
\begin{document}
  \pstVerb{realtime srand}
  \psLoop{10}{%
    \begin{pspicture}(-2,-2)(2,2)
       \edef\COOR{}\multido{\iA=0+36,\iB=0+1}{10}{%
         \pnode(!Rand 1 add \iA\space PtoC){P\iB}\xdef\COOR{\COOR(P\iB)}}   
       \expandafter\pspolygon\COOR
       \psline[linecolor=green,arrows=-*](P3)
    \end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]