# Draw squiggly circle with tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am attempting to draw a squiggly circle in order to delineate an area of a figure, but in a manner that emphasizes the arbitrariness of the precise boundary - something like the circle below, but more distorted and random. I cannot figure out a good way of approaching this with TikZ - any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: The closest earlier post I could find is https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/508410/194703.

Comment: These solutions work great, thanks - I must have been searching with the wrong terms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[declare function={rr=1+0.1*rnd;}]
 \draw plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,45,...,315}] (\t:2*rr);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can make it a pic, and thus make the "randomness" parameters like amplitude or the number of samples.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[pics/random circle/.style={code={
  \tikzset{random circle/.cd,#1}
  \def\pv##1{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/random circle/##1}}% 
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\nextt}{360/\pv{samples}}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\lastt}{360-\nextt}
  \draw plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,\nextt,...,\lastt}] 
  (\t:\pv{radius}+rnd*\pv{amplitude});
 }},random circle/.cd,radius/.initial=1,amplitude/.initial=0.1,
 samples/.initial=8]
 \path (0,0) pic{random circle} 
    (4,0) pic[blue]{random circle={radius=2,amplitude=0.3,samples=12}}
    (0,-4) pic[red]{random circle={radius=2,amplitude=0.5,samples=16}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How would I make the "squiggly circles" thicker. I tried adding `thick`, and even `very thick`, as in: `\draw plot[very thick,smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,\nextt,...,\lastt}] `.... However, this seems to have no effect.

Comment: @murray You add `very thick` to the options of `plot`. However, you need `\draw[very thick] plot[smooth cycle,variable=\t,samples at={0,\nextt,...,\lastt}] ...`. Yet, if you use the pic, you only need `pic[very thick]{random circle}`.