# How does \x work without a foreach statement in tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've gone through the second tutorial in the tikz documentation and I was introduced to the use of \x inside of foreach statements to iterate some processes. However, I just found out that \x can appear without a foreach statement. I adapted some code from [another thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/530977/draw-squiggly-circle-with-tikz) to mostly simplify it and ended up with the following;

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=3,very thick]
\draw[samples=500] plot (canvas polar
cs:angle=\x r,radius={50-10*sin(10*\x r)}); %50 and 10 in 50 - 10 ... control the sharpness of each curve, 10 in sin(x) controls number of curves
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

which produces this image:

[image]

However, I don't understand what the \x is doing in this code since there is nothing like a \foreach ... in {1,...,5) statement that determines the range of values that \x can take on. So how is the \x contributing to generating this squiggly line and how is it working in general in a statement like this? Also, why is it followed by an r? Does the r represent a number that multiplies the value that \x takes on?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Very interesting example!
I don't just want to throw hundrets of pages of manual at you, but the [pgfmanual](https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf) *is* very informative.
There you find:

**Plotting a Function**
When you plot a function, the coordinates of the plot data can be computed by evaluating a mathematical
expression. Since pgf comes with a mathematical engine, you can specify this expression and then have
TikZ produce the desired coordinates for you, automatically.
Since this case is quite common when plotting a function, the syntax is easy: Following the plot command
and its local options, you directly provide a *(coordinate expression)*. It looks like a normal coordinate, but
inside you may use a special macro, which is `\x` by default, but this can be changed using the variable
option. The *(coordinate expression)* is then evaluated for different values for `\x` and the resulting coordinates
are plotted.

[...]

`/tikz/domain=<start>:<end>` (no default, initially -5:5)
Sets the domain from which the samples are taken

**Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Operators**
*x*`r`: Converts x to degrees (x is assumed to be in radians).
*(So basically the same as `*180/3.14` - my comment)*

---

So basically, this code snippet draws 500 samples from the range of -5:5 and takes these values as polar coordinate angles in radians. Then it computes the radius as `50-10*sin(10*<angle converted to degrees>)` for each sample. Through these points, it draws a line.

Comment: Thanks! I think there's a typo initial x at the beginning of the sentence under "Syntax for Mathematical Expressions". Also, how do you say the range is -5:5? You said there is no default but I don't see where the code I posted specifies that.

Comment: I copied that from the manual, including the x. It is supposed to be the value x. So `\x r` like in your example converts `\x` from radians to degrees and `42 r` converts 42 from radians to degrees.  
I also find the "no default" to be confusing, but this is straight from the manual as well. It seems to be the value that applies if you specify nothing. You can try it yourself by specifying `\draw[samples=500, domain=-5:0]`.

Comment: For your reference, if you want to check for yourself, currently the section numbers in the manual are 22.5 (Plotting a Function) and 94.2 (Syntax for Mathematical Expressions: Operators), but these change with each version I think. You can always Ctrl+F for the headings, though

Comment: I played a bit with the domain and, while it's not clear from this example what the default domain is, it seems to be the case that the squiggly circle above requires a domain range of at least 8 units (like 3:10 or even 20:27) to not cut off any section of the circle. One last thing: say the domain is defined as -5:5. So, the 500 samples are taken as random values between -5:5? Like 0.23, 3.22, -3.19, 0.01, etc? And all these are read as radians, and then converted into degrees, correct?

Comment: You would expect the required range to be 6.28 (2 pi) for a full circle. I think the samples are drawn uniformly, so if your domain is 0:1 and you draw 101 samples, they are in 0.01 intervals. Regarding your last question, I think tikz expects degrees (almost?) everywhere. So you could just as well have your range run from 0 to 360 and drop the `r`. That might be even clearer here, actually!

Comment: Thank you for the help! I really appreciate it and you have deservedly won my check mark. Just as an idea, you provided plenty of very useful additional info in these comments so it may be worth to add some of that info to your answer for future readers who don't consult or look over these comments.